# Tableau and Mongodb: WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api

Hi guys I'm trying to conect mongodb to tableau but I'm getting some errors and idk why. This is what a get:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.9\bin>mongosqld --schema schema.drdl --mongo-uri localhost
2019-01-03T11:01:39.503-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] mongosqld starting: version=v2.9.0 pid=14140 host=DESKTOP-BIP3KIF
2019-01-03T11:01:39.663-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: d8cbef70c1e612d299f120dd997b3872ab32a679
2019-01-03T11:01:39.663-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.2n-fips  7 Dec 2017 (built with OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018)
2019-01-03T11:01:39.663-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] options: {schema: {path: "schema.drdl"}, mongodb: {net: {uri: "localhost"}}}
2019-01-03T11:01:39.663-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
2019-01-03T11:01:39.663-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten]
listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3307: bind: Intento de acceso a un socket no permitido por sus permisos de acceso.
```

It says that I do not have the privileges to do this, but I'm running my cmd as admin, any ideas to solve this?

Here is my guide https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/v2.0/installation/
and I'm stuck in the 5 step

Edit, It seems that the connection is established but I cant see the collections or the documents

[image]

Comment: `Access control is not enabled for mongosqld` is a warning not an error. It refers to the fact that on the opened port anbody has admin permission on the databases without user authentication. Your problem is the bind error (last log line with the Italian? error text).

Comment: @Robert hi rober thx for the answer, exactly, it says that i dont have the provileges to access to that socket, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The process `mongosqld` you are trying to start tries to use TCP port 3307. This port should be usable by anyone, unless it is already used by a different program.

You can type in an cmd.exe shell with admin permissions the command

`netstat -b -p tcp`

It lists all used ports and the processes which use them. Search for port 3307 and check which process blocks it.

Comment: I only have one instance of mongodb running in that port and yes it's installed as a windows service, is that why I cant see my data in tableau? Should i uninstall and install mongodb?

Comment: Oh i thought that these comands `mongodrdl --host example.com -d dbname [-c collname] -o schema.drdl` and `mongosqld --schema schema.drdl --mongo-uri <your.mongohost.com>` were made to run the conector of mongo to tableau, so what should I do? do I have to kill that process who's running in that port?

Comment: Oh I was wrong this is not the mongod but something different and it tries to use port 3307. See my updated answer.

Comment: No process is using that port :( I've already re-installed my mongodb and still not working, idk what else should i do

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but try starting with the option:

```
--noUnixSocket
```

Is it possible you have mysqld running on the box?  I have seen errors like this when the socket is in use. If that doesn't work you may also try setting this option

```
 --addr=127.0.0.1
```